# Understanding MySQL InnoDB locks

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, innodb

I am confused on how MySQL InnoDB locks work.

To understand it in better way, I have conducted below experiment. I have used Spring boot and JPA to insert/update records in below table *(though this question is not related to Spring boot or JPA)*.

**Table name:** `test`

| Column name | Type | Constraint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | Bigint | PK AI |
| name | Varchar |  |
| val | Int |  |
| br_id | Int |  |

**Innodb lock wait timeout:** 50 sec

**Repository:** `ITestRepository.java`

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "update test set val=val+1 where val>:val and br_id=:brId", nativeQuery = true) // Just a random update query
public void updateVal(Integer val, Integer brId);
```

**Service:** `TestService.java`

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public void saveMany(final int brId) { // brId is always passed as 1
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        this.testRepository.updateVal(i, brId); // ======> LINE: 1
        this.testRepository.save(new TestEntity(String.valueOf(i), i, brId)); // ======> LINE: 2
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public void saveOne(final int val, final int brId) { // brId is always passed as 2
    this.testRepository.updateVal(val, brId); // ======> LINE: 3
    this.testRepository.save(new TestEntity(String.valueOf(val), val, brId)); // ======> LINE: 4
}
```

- **NOTE 1:** Table is always truncated before executing any of the below cases.
- **NOTE 2:** It is intentional that above `update` query will not update anything.

**Case 1:** *Triggering only `saveMany` method once*

In this case, everything works fine, and 200 rows gets inserted once the transaction is completed without any error.

**Case 2:** *Triggering `saveMany` first, and then `saveOne` once*

In this case, while `saveMany` is being executed if we trigger `saveOne`, `saveOne` will fail with `Lock wait timeout` exception after 50 sec, and `saveMany` will successfully complete once the loop is over.

**Case 3:** *Commenting `LINE: 1` & `LINE: 3` OR commenting `LINE: 2` & `LINE: 4` and Triggering `saveMany` first, and then `saveOne` once*

In this case, while `saveMany` is being executed if we trigger `saveOne`, everything will work fine and both the methods will complete successfully without any exception.

**Case 4:** *Commenting `LINE: 1` and Triggering `saveMany` first, and then `saveOne` once*

In this case, while `saveMany` is being executed if we trigger `saveOne`, `saveOne` will fail on `LINE: 3` with `lock wait timeout` exception for update operation.

**Case 5:** *Commenting `LINE: 2` and Triggering `saveMany` first, and then `saveOne` once*

In this case, while `saveMany` is being executed if we trigger `saveOne`, `saveOne` will fail on `LINE: 4` with `lock wait timeout` exception for insert operation.

From above cases here are my derivations:

1. Parallel `inserts` or `updates` does not lock tables
2. Parallel `insert` and `update` will lock the table (whichever operation is triggered first will acquire lock first)

I am not able to understand how above two derivations work. I mean from the MySQL documentation, they state that whole table is never locked in InnoDB, and only the rows are locked while performing `inserts` or `updates`. As you can see in above cases, `br_id` is always different for both the methods, and thus `updates` are being performed on different set of rows, then also why `lock wait timeout` exception is raised? Also, parallel `inserts` or `updates` are not causing any issue, how and why?

**EDIT 1:**

If `br_id` is not indexed, then it works like stated in above cases, but if `br_id` is indexed, then `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction` exception is thrown immediately while executing `saveOne` method parallel to `saveMany` method.

Comment: Are val and / or br_id indexed?

Comment: @Shadow No, it is not. I have already mentioned all the available constraints in the table.

Comment: Innodb locks records it needs to scan. If there is no available index, then it may lock all records in the table.

Comment: So you mean that if I index `br_id`, it will not lock the tables? Let me give it a try.

Comment: But still, why parallel `inserts` or `updates` are not causing any issue?

Comment: Inserts do not need to scan the entire table.

Comment: Check my updated question. Even indexing `br_id` is not working.

Comment: check innodb status monitor to understand the deadlock

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL so we can discuss what MySQL does with it.

Comment: `update` query is already mentioned, and normal `insert` query is generated like - `insert into test (name, val, br_id) values (?, ?, ?)`

Comment: Add a tag for the framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
update test
    set val = ...
    where val > ...
      and br_id = ...
```

Since there are no indexes on the relevant columns, all rows are locked.

It would be better to have

```
INDEX(br_id)
```

or

```
INDEX(br_id, val)
```

The latter is better for locating the row(s) to modify, but has the drawback of needing to update the index's BTree.

Be aware that some "locks" are "gap locks".  This involves locking the gap between indexed values.  This can sometimes cause surprises.  (I don't know if such is relevant to this update.)

One tool for looking at the locks is `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`  (Since the info there is transient, it may not show what you need.)

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE ...
((spend lots of time before COMMIT))
COMMIT;
```

That will either delay or deadlock any competing connection that needs the same row locks.

Nearly always InnoDB can see that simply stalling (up to `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` seconds) in order to get the necessary locks.

InnoDB can *always* discover a deadlock, and will `ROLLBACK` one of the transactions, while letting the other finish.

There are a few cases (esp with "gap locking" where InnoDB conservatively declares a deadlock when there might not have been one.  (I don't know if this was your case.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Rick. As I have mentioned, `INDEX(br_id)` is causing deadlock (don't know how and why). Also `update` query is build in such a way that it will not update anything in the table. Also parallel `updates` or parallel `inserts` is not causing any issue. Why and How?

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri - What value of `autocommit` do you run with?  Do you have explicit `BEGIN...COMMIT`?  How long does it take between the Begin and Commit?  Show us the SQL for the Update statement.  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: From my question, the `saveMany` method will commit all the 200 `insert` and `update` operations at once, after few seconds. There is an intentional delay of 2 sec between each `insert-update` operation in `saveMany`. As I said, SQL for `update` is already mentioned in question. See `ITestRepository.java`.

Comment: There are a hundred frameworks obscuring the SQL.  I can advise on SQL, but I can't learn all hundred frameworks.  If you provide the _generated_ SQL, I can help further.  Otherwise, you must wait for someone who knows _both_ the framework you are using _and_ the details of MySQL to give you an answer.  Suggest you add a [tag] to help get such a person.

Comment: To actually see the locks currently used, look at  table performance_schema.data_locks.

Comment: I assume those rows go away at `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.  And what about `data_lock_waits`?